# Vapor Pressure in Heated Pressure Vessel

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, air, evaporation

This question is a bit complex, so thanks in advance for addressing it!

I'm working on a reaction vessel that heats a water solution to 95°C to perform chemical reactions.  The design is a miniaturized pressure vessel that has a seal to withstand pressure and temperature variations.  The design also contains an air gap.  Ambient environment is at atmospheric pressure.  Vessel is a polymer film with adhesive seal.

I am having the *adhesive seal failures* and want to understand the thermodynamics occurring in the vessel.

**Part 1 - Pressure Increase from Air and Vapor**

Assuming a 6uL volume with 5uL of water solution and 1uL of air, what would the internal pressure be when heated from 20°C to 95°C?

My assumption is to use Dalton's law of additive pressures to add the pressure changes to the air and the water vapor.

The change in pressure of dry air would be from Ideal Gas Law (ignoring compressiblility factor):

$$\Delta P_{dry-air} = 101.35kPa\frac{(95+273)°K}{(20+273)°K}-101.35kPa=25.94kPa$$

For water vapor, assuming reaction vessel air stays saturated as temperature increases:

$$\Delta P_{water-vapor}=P_{Sat@95°C}-P_{Sat@20°C}=84.55kPa-2.34kPa=82.21kPa$$

So the increase in total pressure would be:

$$\Delta P_{dry-air} + \Delta P_{water-vapor} = 108.15kPa = 1.07atm$$

*Does this all check-out?*

**Part 2 - Elastic Deformation**

Related to this, partially filled vessels have increased failure rates.  This makes sense to me, since the vessel is made of polymer film and can undergo elastic deformation.  I assume this will cause the vessel volume to increase until elastic force of material equals differential of internal and ambient pressure.  Assuming

So for 1uL head volume (5uL water solution):
$$P_f=\frac{V_i}{V_f}P_i=\frac{1uL}{(1uL+0.25uL)}82.21kPa=65.77kPa$$

So for 4uL head volume (2uL water solution):
$$P_f=\frac{V_i}{V_f}P_i=\frac{4uL}{(4uL+0.25uL)}82.21kPa=77.37kPa$$

Obviously some algebra/numerical iterations are needed to find the equilibrium between volume increase and pressure increase for the rise in temperature.

*Does this check-out as well?*

**Part 3 - Empty Vessels with Air Only**

I have received other anecdotes that the vessel fails most often when empty of water solution.  I haven't tested this, but it seems to invalidate my vapor pressure theory.

*Any thoughts on this?*

Comment: As I understand it, Dalton's law of partial pressures applies only to ideal gas behavior.

Comment: I agree.  Fortunately the error for water vapor at 100kPa and 100°C is 1.6%, which is acceptable for my needs.  Ideal gas behavior for water vapor in power plant steam generators (>200°C, >1 MPa) is not valid.